# Achieving desired layout with proper CSS (not tables)

Tags: html, css

I do not want to use hardcoded widths and table tags to generate the layout I want to achieve, but my CSS skills aren't developed quite yet. My layout is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="DataType">
        Type of Data Request <input type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="Arguments" >
        Arguments <textarea name="arguments" rows="4" cols="45" ></textarea>
    </div>

    <div id="TargetEnvironment" >
        Target Environment <input type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="SubmitButton">
        <button id="btnSubmit">Submit Request</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I would like to have it behave a certain way with CSS. I can achieve it with tables and hard coded margins, but not with proper CSS. Here is what it currently looks like, and what I want it to look like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `float`.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
}

label {
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  clear: right;
  overflow: auto;
}

input, textarea {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <label id="DataType">
        Type of Data Request <input type="text" />
    </label>

    <label id="Arguments" >
        Arguments <textarea name="arguments" rows="4" cols="45" ></textarea>
    </label>

    <label id="TargetEnvironment" >
        Target Environment <input type="text" />
    </label>

    <label id="SubmitButton">
        <button id="btnSubmit">Submit Request</button>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome work! Thanks for the quick reply. I guess I'll have to look up how the float and overflow attributes work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and use float:right on your inputs.

I don't see any problem in using margins or paddings to separate the lines.

Another tip: use the label tag for the labels of your form.

Comment: can you elaborate on this please? I've never used floats before